# React: Adding new element lists using map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add more lists to the job list page after submitting the form similar to the todo list. What actually happens is it will throw `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error and the page will work if I removed the map loop but then I won't be able to add another list. Is there a way I can add new lists using the map loop or another method? Thanks.

myjoblist.js file:

```js
const MyJobList = ({ inputs, joblists }) => (
  <div>
  {joblists.length > 0 && 
  joblists.map(joblist => <div key={joblist.id}>
    <h3>My Job List </h3>
    <h3>{inputs.positionTitle}</h3>
    <p>{inputs.companyName}</p>
    <a href={inputs.jobLink}>{inputs.jobLink}</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <CurrentDate />
  </div>)}
  </div>
);
```

newlist.js file:

```
const NewList = ({ onSubmitList }) => {
  const { inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = CustomForm(onSubmitList);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Create a new job list</h3>
        <input
          placeholder="Position title"
          name="positionTitle"
          type="text"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.positionTitle || ""}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Company name"
          name="companyName"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.companyName || ""}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Job link"
          name="jobLink"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.jobLink || ""}
        />
        <button type="submit">Create list</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

customhooks.js:

```
const CustomHook = callback => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});
  const [joblists, updateJoblists] = useState([])

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    callback(inputs);
    setInputs({});
  };

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    updateJoblists(previousJobLists => [...previousJobLists, {text: inputs}])
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  };

  return {
    handleSubmit,
    handleInputChange,
    inputs,
    joblists
  };
};
```

Here's a link to the mini-project: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputform-with-updated-lists-k4diy?file=/src/myjoblist.js)

**Updated: added more file sources which may be relevant.**

Comment: When you are clicking on "Create list" button then only your "joblists" is not setting up properly due to which while mapping you are getting `undefined`. So please put a check `joblists && joblists.length > 0 && 
      joblists.map` .

Comment: Okay, I added `joblists && ` next to `joblists && joblists.length > 0 && joblists.map`. Unfortunately, it didn't solved the problem as the elements is not rendering after I submitted new lists. The error message did disappear though, so that's progress.

Comment: You expect that your `Navbar` component will receive `joblists` prop, but when you use `Navbar` on your `App.js` you didn't passed `joblists`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
const MyJobList = ({ inputs, joblists }) => (
  <div>
    {joblists && joblists.length > 0 && 
      joblists.map(joblist => <div key={joblist.id}>
        <h3>My Job List </h3>
        <h3>{inputs.positionTitle}</h3>
        <p>{inputs.companyName}</p>
        <a href={inputs.jobLink}>{inputs.jobLink}</a>
        <br />
        <br />
      <CurrentDate />
    </div>)}
  </div>
```

The joblist may not be initialized to an array initially. Initial render will do .length which will throw an error

Comment: I tried it. The error message disappeared, however, the new lists are not rendering :(

Comment: Can you show the code where you're updating joblists ?

Comment: Just updated the question to include more files. You're probably referring to the `newlist.js` file, right? That's where I'm adding new job lists.